# How to define a class with an inner class in runtime using type?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Lets say I want to define the following class using the `type` method in runtime:

```
class Outer(object):
    one = 'one'
    two = 'two'

    class Inner:
        three = 'three'
        four = 'four'
```

So far, I have the following:

```
Outer = type('Outer', (object,), {'one': 'one', 'two': 'two', ...})
```

Unfortunately, I don't have any idea how to define the inner class. How can I do this?

Comment: `{..., 'Inner': type('Inner', {'something_else': 'something else', ...})}`

Comment: @PeterWood Shouldn't there be an empty tuple between 'Inner' and the dictionary?

Comment: @darkhorse the point is you just attach it to the namespace you are passing in to the `type` constructor. There should be a tuple of classes you inherit from as well, yes.

Comment: @darkhorse yes, my mistake, there should be a tuple. I can't edit the comment. If you want to create a correct answer out of it, go ahead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is the following:

```
Outer = type(
    'Outer', 
    (object,), 
    {
        'one': 'one',
        'two': 'two',
        'Inner': type(
            'Inner',
            (),
            {
                'three': 'three',
                'four': 'four'
            }
        )
    }
)
```